# Why do I still see (accepted) answered questions even though I've checked "no answer"?

Tags: bug, new-nav

This *only* happens in the below scenario, when I combine asp.net-web-api2 & web-api tags:

[image]

Comment: -1 because [the circles are not red](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/310998).

Comment: Yellow circle. ARRRRGGGGHHHH!!

Comment: +1 for printing a screenshot, marking it up with an actual yellow highlighter and scanning it back in.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That must have been pretty amazing penmanship to clip exactly to pixel boundaries and precisely emulate the appearance of a software highlighting tool.

Comment: @Joren Good point. +2, then.

Comment: @Gothdo well it doesn't say it has to be a *red* circle, just **freehand circles**.

Comment: I never knew trivia could get so meta until I read these comments

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks like it has something to do with the fact that [web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api) is a synonym of [asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api).  When I search the same way you did I get the bad results but when I replace [web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api) with [asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) in the search box, I get the expected results:

[image]

Comment: it's certainly odd because it's not happening with other tag synonyms (see "cordova-plugins" - "phonegap-plugins", for example

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu Those two tags are not actually synonyms as far as the tag system is concerned.  What is interesting is when you type in a synonym tag it should take you directly to the main tag([tag:cpp] gives you [tag:c++]).  For some reason typing in [tag:web-api] not only works but gives you results instead of redirecting you to [tag:asp.net-web-api].